# Snakeviz-like visual profiler for Java hprof or honest profiler

Tags: java, profiling

I've been using CPU profilers for both Java and Python lately, and in Python we have SnakeViz, a nice web based tool that visualizes cProfile dumps.

In Java I've been using hprof and honest-profiler to generate my dumps, and this project to visualize them: https://github.com/cykl/hprof2flamegraph

The flamegraph itself is a great tool, but it is a single interactive SVG which is **very** heavy on my browser, especially for big projects.

Is there anything more light-weight for visualizing Java hprof dumps?

Comment: Stackoverflow does not allow tool recommendations, so somebody will probably close this question. But I would recommend to just try the standard profilers (JProfiler, VisualVM, Yourkit) , they can all open HPROF snapshots.

Comment: thank you @IngoKegel, yeah I know that it doesn't allow this but I couldn't find an answer googling it, I wish there was a StackExchange site for tool recommendations